# (How) shall I remove wpa_supplicant if server doesn't have Wifi?

Tags: ubuntu, wpa-supplicant

Ubuntu 20.04LTS, headless machine, with no Wifi card.

`wpa_supplicant` is running and wasting my resources (although not too much I think).

I know I can disable it with `systemctl stop|disable|mask`.

However, (how) can/shall I completely remove it from Ubuntu 20.04?

Is it safe to remove it? I don't have GUI. It's a headless machine which can only be accessed remotely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt remove wpasupplicant
```

Will remove it, make sure it use `apt purge wpasupplicant` after. You can always type `sudo apt remove wpa` then press TAB to autocomplete any possibilities (might have to TAB twice).

I mention the TAB completion because on my system I also have `wpa-sycophant`, which you might also have and not need.

As far as whether or not you should, it **is** only for Wi-Fi, technically it is for the Authentication method within WiFi *IEEE 802.11* so I guess if your not using it, you don't need it. If you want to check exactly what it does you can run `man wpa_supplicant` and read it's description. You should be able to manage your connections with `nmcli`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

OTOH, if you want to learn something about the resource usage of `wpa_supplicant`. In my case (and I use wpa_supplicant):

```bash
$ pgrep wpa_supplicant
407
486 
$ sudo pmap 407 | tail -n 1
 total    11792K
$ sudo pmap 486 | tail -n 1
 total    12056K
```

So - quite a lot of memory usage - but again, `wpa_supplicant` is quite active on my host.